# Convert Query Builder to Eloquent Builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I can not extract the result in groupby, the query builder below works very well but I want it to Eloquent.
I want to display only the folders that are already in the relationship?

how to convert a query builder to Eloquent?

```
$folders = Folder::select('folders.id','folders.title')
    ->join('matters', 'matters.folder_id', '=', 'folders.id')
    ->join('tutorials', 'tutorials.matter_id', '=', 'matters.id')
    ->whereDate('tutorials.start', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->where('tutorials.status','=','0')
    ->groupby('folders.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This is eloquent builder...

Comment: I meant Eloquent without join, i.e : $ folders = Folder :: with ('matters') ....

Comment: then u need to build the relationship between them

Comment: the relationships are already exists in the models
class Tutorial Model{
public function matter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Matter::class);
    }
}
class Matter Model{
public function folder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Folder::class);
    }    public function tutorials()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tutorial::class);
    }


}
class Folder Model{
    public function matters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Matter::class);
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `Floder` hasMany `Matter`, `Matter` hasMany `Tutorial`.

You can create the [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship in `Folder` Model, and use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to find the `folders`

```php
$folders = Folder::whereHas('tutorials', function($query) {
                     $query->whereDate('tutorials.start', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
                           ->where('tutorials.status','=','0');
                 })->select('title', 'id')->get();
```

if you don't have `hasManyThrough` relationship, you can still get `folders` like this one:

```php
$folders = Folder::whereHas('maters.tutorials', function($query) {
                     $query->whereDate('tutorials.start', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
                           ->where('tutorials.status','=','0');
                 })->select('title', 'id')->get();
```

Comment: I got this error  Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on array

Comment: @visulo sorry for the syntax problem. I have updated it.

Comment: can i ask you another question?

Comment: @visulo what is it?

Comment: I cannot resolve this request?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873653/laravel-eloquent-relationship-polymorphic